# i need to insert values into two different table with single query

Tags: php, mysql

How do I join these two queries and execute them as a single query to insert values in two tables:

```
$sql = mysql_real_escape_string('INSERT INTO admin_export(datetime, product_name, item_code,quantity,subject,export_no) VALUES').implode(',', $row_data);
$sql2 = "insert into `itflower_exportno` (admin_exportno) values('$exportno1')";
```

Comment: You can't do multiple table inserts in a single query

Comment: why you want to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your two INSERT statements with a semicolon into the single variable.

This(mysql_*) extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. Switching to PreparedStatements is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

You can however use transactions as following example.

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO users (username, password)
  VALUES('test', 'test');
INSERT INTO profiles (userid, bio, homepage) 
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'Hello world!', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the code are two different inserts.
MySQL doesn't allow for multiple inserts to be run in the same query so you will have to do one first and then the other.

However you can insert multiple rows in the same table in just one query, basically you are restricted to do all the insert you want in one table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.
If you want to do it because you are afraid of the integrity of the data, use [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) .
Second, use suitable [transaction isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/dynindex-isolevel.html), to ensure that data are reading correctly.